# Problem generating sources and connectin SOAP SugarCRM

Tags: soap, wsdl, sugarcrm

With Eclipse IDE, I've a file with extension .wsdl

I click with the right mouse button, "Web Services" > "Generate Client" and when I click "Finish" I receive this error

```
IWAB0399E Error in generating Java from WSDL:  javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException (at /definitions/types/xsd:schema): faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'.: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Final de archivo prematuro.
```

Where is the problem? In a MacOs this working

And I want paste the full WSDL file, but is huge.